# How manage the Tab Bar Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem with the tab bar controller. My application is composed of a tab bar controller with two views. In the first I insert a record into a sqlite database, and in the second there is a table view that contains all the database records. I would like that when I insert a new record in the db, the table view was updated. This happens only in the method viewDidLoad, namely only one time. Is there a way to know when the tab bar item changes and then update the table? I had tried to use the properties: create an object of the ViewController class, and access to the property from an other ViewController...but I couldn't.
Thanks

```
//Insert new record view

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char*dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &DB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Example(Id, name) VALUES (?,?)"];

    const char *insert_stmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare(DB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [name.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);    
    }


    if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"OK");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(DB);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error");
}

SecondViewController *svc=[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibname:@"Second" bundle:nil]; 
[svc.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Can you post some of the related code so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: I don't know what to post...because this is a general problem...

Comment: Just post your code so we can answer your question and help future users

Comment: Please see my updated answer below

Answer (score 0):

At the end of where you're inserting your record in the db, you could send out a notification that will alert `SecondViewController`

Start by replacing

```
SecondViewController *svc=[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibname:@"Second" bundle:nil]; 
[svc.tableView reloadData];
```

With:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DidUpdateDatabase" object:self];
```

And in `viewDidLoad` of `SecondViewController` add this block to listen for the changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"DidUpdateDatabase"
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  [self.tableView reloadData];
                                              }];
```

This is called a notification pattern that allows objects to be decoupled from each other and still hold communication.

EDIT:

Another solution is in `SecondViewController`'s `viewDidAppear` call `[self.tableView reloadData]`. This will cause it to reload every time the user goes to that view

Comment: Yes! Perfect! This is the method that I was searching! Thanks a lot for your help!